# How to create my own 'Smarty' like tags

Tags: php, preg-replace, templating

what is the simplest method to do the following

Look at a block of text and anywhere it finds %sometxt% replace that with something else,

So basically any text that is enclosed within a set of percentage signs similar to how Smarty do this?

Comment: What about a text that contains two `%` characters like "Reiku 50% vs. Razor 80%"? Can you define what "sometxt" is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *simplest method* you asked for:

```
$blockOfText = str_replace('%sometxt%', 'something else', $blockOfText);
```

You just replace it with [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace).

Answer (score 2):

```
$newText = preg_replace('/%.+?%/', 'replacedText', $text);
```

Should do it. `replacedText` needs to be whatever you want to replace `%sometxt%` with.

The regexp `%.+?%` means

> Fine a `%` sign, followed by any character until I find another `%` sign.

The `?` makes the expression 'lazy', so it will match up to the first occurrence of `%`.

Comment: Why the `i` modifier? Since you match all characters it would not be necessary to ignore case?

Comment: For matching actual tags he should add the actual variable text between the % signs in you expression. Furthermore your expression now uses the % signs as a delimiter. And lastly, it is possible to do multiple replaces with a single method call by passing an array of patterns and an array of replacements.

Comment: Aha, do you want `%` be the delimiters? Or you have missed it? :)